# Javascript to print my pdf file

Tags: javascript

In my tomcat webapps folder contain one PDF I need to button press to new window show the file and print option open using JavaScript Is possible or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function print() {
    var file = window.open('http://url/to/pdf');
    file.print();
}

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick=print()>
```

Comment: I think you'll find in at least some browsers the `file.print()` will fail

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible. Determine the url of the pdf on the tomcat web container and then the following JavaScript should work:

```
var pdfWin = window.open('MyPDF.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
pdfWin.focus();
pdfWin.print();
```

Comment: I think you'll find in at least some browsers the `pdfWin.print()` will fail

Comment: I try above code.But button click to not file load complete to open the print dialog and then print it will return empty document.